# trouble with fibonacci number generation

Tags: prolog, fibonacci

Below is my Nth fibonacci number finding predicate which is ok:

```
f(0,0).
f(1,1).
f(N,R):-P is N-1,Q is N-2,f(P,T1),f(Q,T2),R is T1+T2.
```

And I am trying to generate fibonacci numbers with the following predicate:

```
fgen(0,0).
fgen(1,1).
fgen(A,B):-fgen(X,Y),A is X+1,f(A,T),B is T.
```

when I query with `fgen(X,Y).`

It shows:

```
?- fgen(X,Y).

X = 0
Y = 0 ;

X = 1
Y = 1 ;

X = 1
Y = 1 ;
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

I used the trace command and the following resulted:

```
?- trace,fgen(X,Y).
   Call: (9) fgen(_G281, _G282) ? creep
   Exit: (9) fgen(0, 0) ? creep

X = 0
Y = 0 ;
   Redo: (9) fgen(_G281, _G282) ? creep
   Exit: (9) fgen(1, 1) ? creep

X = 1
Y = 1 ;
   Redo: (9) fgen(_G281, _G282) ? creep
   Call: (10) fgen(_L178, _L189) ? creep
   Exit: (10) fgen(0, 0) ? creep
^  Call: (10) _G281 is 0+1 ? creep
^  Exit: (10) 1 is 0+1 ? creep
   Call: (10) f(1, _L179) ? creep
   Exit: (10) f(1, 1) ? creep
^  Call: (10) _G282 is 1 ? creep
^  Exit: (10) 1 is 1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) fgen(1, 1) ? creep

X = 1
Y = 1 ;
   Redo: (10) f(1, _L179) ? creep
^  Call: (11) _L207 is 1-1 ? creep
^  Exit: (11) 0 is 1-1 ? creep
^  Call: (11) _L208 is 1-2 ? creep
^  Exit: (11) -1 is 1-2 ? creep
   Call: (11) f(0, _L209) ? creep
   Exit: (11) f(0, 0) ? abort
% Execution Aborted
```

I am trying to find the bug, but failing. How to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

For starters,

```
fgen(A,B) :- fgen(X, Y), A is X+1, f(A, T), B is T.
```

is the same as

```
fgen(A,B) :- fgen(X, _), A is X+1, f(A, B).
```

So you have two problems. One is that you're generating and then throwing away Y, and the singleton warning should have alerted you to this. Singleton warnings should always be responded to by replacing the variable with _; if it looks like this turns your code into nonsense, your code is nonsense. :)

The other problem is that `B is T` is unnecessary (and using `is/2` here instead of `=/2` buys you nothing, because there's no arithmetic on the right-hand side).

So let's try this:

```
fgen(A, B) :- fgen(X, A), B is X + A.
```

This is almost working:

```
?- fgen(X, Y).
X = Y, Y = 0 ;
X = Y, Y = 1 ;
X = Y, Y = 0 ;
X = 1,
Y = 2 ;
X = Y, Y = 0 ;
X = 2,
Y = 3 ;
X = Y, Y = 0 ;
X = 3,
Y = 5 ;
X = Y, Y = 0 ;
X = 5,
Y = 8 ;
X = Y, Y = 0 ;
X = 8,
Y = 13 ;
X = Y, Y = 0 ;
X = 13,
Y = 21 .
```

All those meaningless zeros should tell you that you don't need your first base case at all. After all, adding zeros won't change anything. If you remove that base case, you get the behavior you want:

```
?- fgen(X, Y).
X = Y, Y = 1 ;
X = 1,
Y = 2 ;
X = 2,
Y = 3 ;
X = 3,
Y = 5 ;
X = 5,
Y = 8 ;
X = 8,
Y = 13 ;
X = 13,
Y = 21
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your `f/2` is ***not*** OK:

```
6 ?- f(10,X).

X = 55 ;
ERROR: (user://2:68):
        Out of local stack
```

Your clauses should be made **mutually-exclusive**:

```
f(0,0).
f(1,1).
f(N,R):-N>1,
        P is N-1,Q is N-2,f(P,T1),f(Q,T2),R is T1+T2.
```

Without the `N>1` test, on restart, the deepest goal `f(0,T2)` is re-matched with the third rule, going one-way into the negative numbers, without ever returning. Now, with the mutually-exclusive clauses, this mis-match is blocked and the predicate becomes deterministic:

```
8 ?- f(10,X).

X = 55 ;

No
```

Perhaps you tried to generate all possible values, but got an error:

```
9 ?- f(A,B).

A = 0,    B = 0 ;    
A = 1,    B = 1 ;
ERROR: (user://5:147):
        Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
^  Exception: (8) _G230>1 ? abort
% Execution Aborted
```

because the first argument must be a fully instantiated number, to be used with `>` and `is`.

Thus your second predicate, `fgen(A,B)`. It is a bit unclear, but judging by the call `f(A,T)` it intends for `A` to be an index, and `B` its corresponding Fibonacci number, generating one by one the sequence of answers `(0,0) , (1,1) , (2,1), (3,2) , (4,3), (5,5) , (6,8) , ...`. To enumerate the indices, we can define

```
% natural(0).
% natural(A):- natural(B), A is B+1.

natural(N):- znat(0,N).
znat(N,N).
znat(A,N):- B is A+1, znat(B,N).
```

and then simply

```
fgen(A,B):- natural(A), f(A,B).
```

Now,

```
12 ?- fgen(A,B).

A = 0,    B = 0 ;    
A = 1,    B = 1 ;    
A = 2,    B = 1 ;    
A = 3,    B = 2 ;    
A = 4,    B = 3 ;    
A = 5,    B = 5 ;    
A = 6,    B = 8
```

The first (commented-out) version of `natural/1` creates a linear length execution stack. The second version runs in constant stack space.

Of course, your `f/2` is doubly-recursive, so it will exhaust the stack much earlier than `natural` ever could.